# google geocoder (reverse geocoding) WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, .net-6.0

I am trying to reverse geocode some coordinates using .net6. I am using the googlegeocoder with a google's api.

I am hiding the API key for security reasons.

```
            IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() { ApiKey = "" };



            static async Task<IEnumerable<Address>> getPlaceAsync(IGeocoder geocoder)
            {
                IEnumerable<Address> addresses = await geocoder.ReverseGeocodeAsync(51.683, -1.68847);



                return addresses;
            }

            var ff = getPlaceAsync(geocoder);
```

[image: This is the response]

The response is when I place the breakpoint after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Your getPlaceAsync method is async.  You need to await the call

```
var results = await GetPlaceAsync(geocoder);
```

As for the package itself.  [Geocoding.Google](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geocoding.Google) is not an official google client library.  it hasnt been developed on since 2017, which means its probably not going to support .net 6.  Which may be why running the code even after fixing your await issue will result in

> Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocodingException: There was an error processing the geocoding request. See Status or InnerException for more information.
> at Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocoder.ProcessWebResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
> at Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocoder.ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocoder.ReverseGeocodeAsync(Double latitude, Double longitude)
> at Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocoder.Geocoding.IGeocoder.ReverseGeocodeAsync(Double latitude, Double longitude)
> at Program.<$>g__GetPlaceAsync|0_0(IGeocoder geocoder) in C:\YouTube\dev\Blazor\GoogleGeocoderTest\GoogleGeocoderTest\Program.cs:line 15

As far as i know there is no offical Google .net client library for Geocoding api.